# Fast dynamic JavaScript WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

Right now I am using the **TinyMCE** wysiwyg editor within my projects.

However there are some disadvantages with tinyMCE:

1. Tons of GET requests
2. Big
3. It is **slow**. I can't have a large number of TinyMCE editors at the same time. (Especially in IE)
4. Changing the DOM position of the TinyMCE caused issues where the listeners got lost.
5. Complicated to generate new TinyMCE editors dynamically during "runtime".
6. Hard to control by jQuery

Is there any WYSIWYG editor you would suggest?

A big plus would be a jQuery based editor as this project works with jQuery anyway.

Comment: I would suggest specifying a list of requirements/needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try CKEditor http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery (formerly FCKeditor)

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest jHtmlArea, its **jQuery** powered and its quite fast

- 1 image file using CSS Image sprites
- 1 line of javascript, 1 line of CSS

I have used it in a lot of projects before and its quite good.

http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is Slow!

If you need something as fast as possible, you could use http://unverse.net/Whizzywig-2011, but its ugly, so there is also something like http://aloha-editor.org/